# getting some words out from a "string" in python

Tags: python

I have a question about strings in python.

```
    s = "name Harry Potter"
```

if I just want to get the "Harry Potter" in the string, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer here

`print(s.split('name ')[1])`

Answer (score 3):

If you now where Harry Potter is in S

`newString=s[5:]`

5 is the index of the frst letter of Harry Potter

For a more complete example

```
s = "name Harry Potter"

stringToSearch="Harry Potter"

indexOfString=s.index(stringToSearch)

newString=s[indexOfString:indexOfString+len(stringToSearch)]

print(newString)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the value that you want to remove is always "name ", then:

```
s1 = s.replace("name ", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split it, If it's that you want. 
Let's say you have a long string example: "name Harry Potter name Stargate name Titanic"

```
s = "name Harry Potter name Stargate name Titanic"
mylist = s.split("name")
print (mylist)
['', ' Harry Potter ', ' Stargate ', ' Titanic']
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `re` module. This module has a lot of utilities for searching strings, it might interest you

```
import re
string = "name Harry Potter"
name = re.findall("Harry Potter", string)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem very useful to pass in the string that you want to get back. I think what OP wanted was to get whatever was after "name ". Otherwise this is a very convoluted way of writing `print("Harry Potter")`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want:

```
for element in s.split(" "):
    if any(x == element for x in ["Harry","Potter"]):
        print(element)
```